# How to convert date with awk

Tags: macos, bash, date, awk

My file `temp.txt`

```
ID53,20150918,2015-09-19,,0,CENTER<br>
ID54,20150911,2015-09-14,,0,CENTER<br>
ID55,20150911,2015-09-14,,0,CENTER
```

I need to replace and convert the 2nd field (yyyymmdd) for seconds

I try it, but only the first line is replaced

```
awk -F"," '{ ("date -j -f ""%Y%m%d"" ""20150918"" ""+%s""") | getline $2; print }' OFS="," temp.txt
```

and tried to like this

```
awk -F"," '{system("date -j -f ""%Y%m%d"" "$2" ""+%s""") | getline $2; print }' temp.txt
```

the output is:

```
1442619474
sh: 0: command not found
ID53,20150918,2015-09-19,,0,CENTER
1442014674
ID54,20150911,2015-09-14,,0,CENTER
1442014674
ID55,20150911,2015-09-14,,0,CENTER
```

Using `gsub` also could not

```
awk -F"," '{gsub($2,"system("date -j -f ""%Y%m%d"" "$2" ""+%s""")",$2); print}' OFS="," temp.txt 

awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    {gsub($2,"system("date -j -f ""%Y%m%d"" "$2" >>>  ""+% <<< s""")",$2); print}
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
    extra )
```

I need the output to be so. How to?

```
ID53,1442619376,2015-09-19,,0,CENTER
ID54,1442014576,2015-09-14,,0,CENTER
ID55,1442014576,2015-09-14,,0,CENTER
```

Comment: I think you have your answer [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306217/timestamp-to-epoch-in-a-csv-with-gawk

Comment: @tstark81: the only problem is that this is tagged [tag:osx] meaning Mac OS X, and Mac OS X has BSD `awk`, not GNU `awk`.  GNU `awk` has some powerful extensions added for date processing (and [Timestamp to epoch in a CSV file with `gawk`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306217/timestamp-to-epoch-in-a-csv-with-gawk) likely covers them.  It isn't much help on Mac OS X unless the user installs GNU `awk`, though.

Comment: In a [previous answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17692959/1259917), I used date on a mac with its default awk.  It's not formatted for your case, but maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This **GNU `awk`** script should make it. If it is not yet installed on your mac, I suggest installing `macport` and then GNU `awk`. You can also install a decent version of `bash`, `date` and other important utilities for which the default are really disappointing on OSX.

```
BEGIN { FS = ","; OFS = FS; }
{
    y = substr($2, 1, 4);
    m = substr($2, 5, 2);
    d = substr($2, 7, 2);
    $2 = mktime(y " " m " " d " 00 00 00");
    print;
}
```

Put it in a file (e.g. `txt2ts.awk`) and process your file with:

```
$ awk -f txt2ts.awk data.txt
ID53,1442527200,2015-09-19,,0,CENTER<br>
ID54,1441922400,2015-09-14,,0,CENTER<br>
ID55,1441922400,2015-09-14,,0,CENTER
```

Note that we do not have the same timestamps. I let you try to understand where it comes from, it is another problem.

Explanations: `substr(s, m, n)` returns the `n`-characters sub-string of `s` that starts at position `m` (starting with 1). `mktime("YYYY MM DD HH MM SS")` converts the date string into a timestamp (seconds since epoch). `FS` and `OFS` are the input and output filed separators, respectively. The commands between the curly braces of the `BEGIN` pattern are executed at the beginning only while the others are executed on each line of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use substr:

```
printf "%s-%s-%s", substr($6,0,4), substr($6,5,2), substr($6,7,2)
```

Assuming that the 6th field was 20150914, this would produce 2015-09-14